# CEFSharp jquery code does not work

Tags: c#, jquery, cefsharp

I am using CEFsharp browser in my winform app, trying to execute jQuery code, when I try the code in chrome inspect it works fine, but it doesn't work with

```
// browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('input[name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]').val('Google');");

// browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('input[name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]').value = 'google'");
// MessageBox.Show("!");
// browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(DraftTxt.Text);

await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(DraftTxt.Text);

browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('input[name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]').val('Google');");
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('input[name=\"session[password]\"]').val('"+txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToString()+"');");
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByTagName(\"form\")[1].submit();");
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('input[name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]').val('test');");
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('input[name=\"session[username_or_email]\"]').val('test');");
```

Comment: Are you waiting until after the document has loaded?  In CEF C++ this is `ClientHandler::OnLoadingStateChange` when isLoading == 0.

Comment: Yes I already made a condition:

if (!e.Browser.IsLoading)
            {
             }

Comment: If you're just checking the status instead of waiting for an event, could it be running before loading even begins for the document?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: Open Devtools for debugging http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ShowDevTools_1.htm

Comment: I already replaced with native Javascript